# Creating a jquery ui button in a hidden div is not working when div is shown

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a div which I want to hide .. then load with html which includes a button .. then show it again - and have the button be a jquery ui button.

```
$("#InfoBox").hide("slide", {
    direction: "right"
}, 1000, function () {
    $("#InfoBox").html($("#InfoBoxClone").html());
});

$("#butEditor").button();

$("#InfoBox").show("slide", {
    direction: "left"
}, 1000);
```

When it shows, it certainly looks like a jquery ui button - but doesn't behave as one.

Not easy to explain so I made a jsfiddle to show the bare bones of it.

http://jsfiddle.net/Upland/JFUuH/6/

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Is the issue with the `<button id="butEditor">Click to Launch</button>` button? If so, what's not working the way you expect?

Comment: as you can see in the fiddle, it's not a button, it's just a "graphic". Compare it with the Switch button above it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are changing the HTML that is in the info box.  This will copy all of the rendered HTML in `InfoBoxClone`, but it will not copy the javascript event handlers that are in place.  These javascript event handlers are created when `.button()` is called on the button, which is what gives you the hover and click behaviors.

I'd recommend hiding and showing the HTML rather than copying the hidden HTML.  Not only will you not have this bug, but you currently have duplicate ids because you are duplicating the HMTL.

Comment: But I *want* to change the html that's in #infobox ... I have several buttons each with their own infobox content (the fiddle is bare-bones, so one button). But I take your point about the duplicate IDs so changed it to class ( http://jsfiddle.net/Upland/JFUuH/10/ ) ... I just don't get why it doesn't behave as I expect.

Comment: Because you are copying the HTML after calling `button`.  As I originally said, you are copying the HTML, but not the event handlers.  Even if you have 100 sections, I would toggle hidden, rather than copying the HTML.